# Can't build a Strapi Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, strapi

I'm trying to follow the official Strapi documentation to build a Dockerfile with docker-compose (separate MySQL) but I'm stuck at a weird step I'm not sure where it comes from. It's the node-gyp command that it can't execute...
I have a Nuxt application in the "nuxt-app" folder and the strapi in the "strapi" folder, both at the root. The docker-compose is also at the root:

strapi/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
# Installing libvips-dev for sharp Compatibility
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm bash git vips-dev
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /opt/
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && yarn install
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
USER node
RUN ["yarn", "build"]
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["yarn", "develop"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  strapi:
    container_name: strapi
    build: strapi/
    image: strapi:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./strapi/.env
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_HOST: strapiDB
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: ${ADMIN_JWT_SECRET}
      APP_KEYS: ${APP_KEYS}
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ./strapi/config:/opt/app/config
      - ./strapi/src:/opt/app/src
      - ./strapi/package.json:/opt/package.json
      - ./strapi/yarn.lock:/opt/yarn.lock
      - ./strapi/.env:/opt/app/.env
      - ./strapi/public/uploads:/opt/app/public/uploads
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    networks:
      - strapi
    depends_on:
      - strapiDB

  strapiDB:
    container_name: strapiDB
    platform: linux/amd64 #for platform error on Apple M1 chips
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: strapi/.env
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./strapi/strapi-data:/var/lib/mysql
      #- ./data:/var/lib/mysql # if you want to use a bind folder
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - strapi

volumes:
  strapi-data:

networks:
  strapi:
    name: Strapi
    driver: bridge
```

There is the error I'm facing:

```
31.08 [5/5] Building fresh packages...
31.80 error /opt/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
31.80 Exit code: 127
31.80 Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
31.80 Arguments: 
31.80 Directory: /opt/node_modules/sharp
31.80 Output:
31.80 sharp: Detected globally-installed libvips v8.14.3
31.80 sharp: Building from source via node-gyp
31.80 /bin/sh: node-gyp: not found
```

Please note that I do have an .env file in the strapi/ folder.
I'm working with a Macbook Pro that have M1 Pro chip